# How not to redirect Google Webmaster Tools validator

Tags: regex, .htaccess, google-search-console

I'm using the following RewriteRule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /index.php?show=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Now I've signed up for Google Webmaster Tools, which tries to validate the website ownership about once a month by requesting a document called `google(someSerialNumber).html`. But because of my RewriteRule it gets redicrected and the validation fails, so I have to remove the rule temporary when validating manually and that annoys me.

How would the correct regex be for rewriting everything except the validation document?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using a negative lookahead:

```
^(?!google\([^\)]+\)\.html$)(.*)\.html$
```

If there's only one serial number, just put it in the regex instead of `[^\)]+`.

The regex won't match `google(someSerialNumber).html` because of the negative lookahead.